# in try and catch when Enter invalid thing back from beginning i want correct the error and go to next

Tags: try-catch

```
import java.util.*;
public class TestBakery{
public static void  main (String [] args)
{

Scanner read=new Scanner(System.in);

boolean OK=true;
int choice=0;

//loop and try-catch

while(OK)
{
try{
System.out.println("ِEnter name of bakery");
String nameBak=read.next();
System.out.println("Enter the max number of cookie");
int nm=read.nextInt();
Bakery b=new Bakery(nameBak,nm);


System.out.println("\n menue :");

System.out.println(" \n 1- To add \n 2- To sell Cookie \n 3-to disply");
System.out.println("Enter choice:");
choice=read.nextInt();
if (choice==1)
{
System.out.println("Enter number of calories:");
double calories=read.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter number quantity:");
int quantity=read.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter Price: ");
double price=read.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter flavor:");
char flavor=read.next().charAt(0);
Cookie C1=new Cookie(flavor,calories,quantity,price);
if (b.addCookie(C1))
OK=false;

}
if (choice==2)
{
System.out.println("Enter flavor:");
char f=read.next().charAt(0);
System.out.println("Enter number quantity:");
int q=read.nextInt();
System.out.println("sellCookie is:");
if (b.sellCookie(f,q))
System.out.println(" OK");
}
if (choice==2)
{
System.out.println("Enter number of calories:");
double c=read.nextDouble();
b.displayByCalories (c);
}

}

catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
{
System.out.println(e);
read.next();
}
catch(InputMismatchException e)
{
System.out.println(e);
read.next();

}

}

}




}
```

//the problem is that  when Enter invalid thing back from beginning
but i want correct the error and go to next 
 (for example ) this sample run :

```
ِEnter name of bakery

sss

Enter the max number of cookie

30

 menue :


 1- To add 
 2- To sell Cookie 
 3-to disply

Enter choice:

1

Enter number of calories:

30

Enter number quantity:

3

Enter Price: 

4

Enter flavor:

g

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: please Enter valid flavor V ,C or P

P

ِEnter name of bakery:

...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you are trying to use exceptions as a flow control mechanism. Which is, not to put too fine a point on it, *wrong*.

Even if you succeeded, it would be ugly.

That being said, if you insist, you need to wrap each question section with a try catch and a loop **separately**.

Comment: please i need answer quickly :(

Comment: Put the try catch loop around EACH question.